# How to get Windows app store dev center data

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, marketplace, windows-dev-center

I want to know if there is a way to get details of applications posted by a developer in the windows phone store. I'm looking for mainly these details: app downloads, app crash count, user reviews, user ratings.

I have a developer account and want to extract above mentioned details for my own submitted apps from dev center.  The store does not provide any REST APIs to do it. Is there an easy way to do it.

Comment: hello @sunny days am also searching for app statistics( no of downloads, reviews, crash count,.. ect) have u get any solution or api??? please help me

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, there is meanwhile a better answer: Sinde 03/2016 the dev center now provides a REST api to get the windows store statistics.

> Today Dev Center released the Windows Store analytics API, which provides analytics information for your Windows Store apps without requiring logging into Dev Center. Using a REST API you can retrieve the same information you see in Dev Center for app and in-app purchase acquisitions, ratings and reviews, as well as app health.  This new API provides quick access to reports without the time required to log into Dev Center, chose specific reports, and then download them. This can be especially useful if you would like to provide quick app information to marketing or finance, or run advanced analysis of data using your own tools (Excel, Power BI, etc.).

Read more at https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/01/windows-store-analytics-api-now-available/#l6dVkg8RyPRMxCjR.99

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a sort of API, I'm not sure you can get all details you want but there is a few, you might want to check that

This is Zune API, which regroups apps and music here is the documentation : http://zunedata.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=API%20Documentation

For example to get app rating use Application Information : http://zunedata.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Application%20Information

Comment: From what I know Zune's service has been discontinued (and replaced by XBOX Music), the API endpoints are all not working as well.

Comment: That is correct @VT Chiew. The zune servie has been discontinued and replaced by http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your best bet is to just manually pull the report spreadsheets down from Dev Center and process everything yourself (hope you like VBScript). Unfortunately there's no supported APIs for getting this data straight from Dev Center for your own account, never mind getting such details from others.

I know there are some on-phone apps that get information like app reviews, such as [AppTracker](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=ceb1e261-9909-e011-9264-00237de2db9e), but as far as I've heard those use page scraping to get data rather than use a more reliable source of data.

Answer (score 0):

here's mu current rating on Italy. Sadly these guys hardly understand my app because I did not implemented Localization. But anyway, I think this requires you to be logged-in in your live/hotmail account depends on what you use on your Windows Phone Dev Center

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/ApplicationDetails/ReviewsForMarket?productId=ddc89efa-36f2-4ad1-9136-9daededc6835&selectedMarket=MX&translateLanguage=en

---

**update**
let's just break that down

- **productId** - Well everybody know what is this for and what value to
  use
- **selectedMarket** - You can play with the values like US, PH, MX, RU
  (probably), IT .. something like that
- **translateLanguage** - en (for
  English translation)

that URL responds with HTML data so you have to parse that out, either make your own, or I recommend to use HAP(HtmlAgilityPack)

You can grab more data by checking the Network session. Just press F12 on Chrome or in IE, not sure in FF (hee hee)

have fun!

Comment: oh and please. Use only for your personal thinge .. not for production. Microsoft might put more securities.

Answer (score -3):

From Dashboard you will see your apps from their you will see quick stats and reviews from users .