# How to get info about an app in the Windows Phone Store API?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

Is there a way to get the following data from the windows phone store without having to parse whole HTML page (I got the app ID)?

```
- Name
- Description
- Access the search (and return only App IDs so I can get what I need for the search reults)
```

I already found [this question regarding zune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912624/how-to-get-windows-phone-store-dev-centre-data), but that seems to be discontinued, if I'm rigjt. Is there soemthing similar for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

you can show the details of the by using MarketplaceDetailTask from Microsoft.Phone.Tasks

here the links , which explains how to show the details page of a app from store.

1)[How to use the Marketplace detail task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

2)http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-use-the-marketplace-tasks-in-windows-phone-8

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't want to redirect the user to the marketplace, but get the information from inside of the app.